# Does a constructor always require a memory allocation

Tags: c#, memory

Considering the following code :

```
void Main()
{
    MemoryContainer mc = new MemoryContainer(0);

    for (byte i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        mc = new MemoryContainer(i);
    }
}

class MemoryContainer
{
    public MemoryContainer(byte someStuff) => stuff = someStuff;

    byte stuff;
}
```

Will this require 1 or 100 memory allocations for a MemoryContainer?

Comment: What happened when  you actually ran the code?  Did it allocate memory continually, or not?

Comment: Please explain : Where would I check this

Comment: I suspect that the answer to this would be implementation dependent, and would depend on how aggressive (or not) any given runtime's garbage collection is, along with how aggressive the JIT optimiser is.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Garbage collection will not be around immediatly after running this loop, so the answer is yes.

Comment: @KobyDouek In the runtimes we use today.  Who knows about some other runtime that someone may have created.

Comment: @noontz You can look at how much memory your program is using over time, or if you wanted to be more precise, you could use a profiler who's job is to give more precise and informative measurements of such things.

Comment: @Servy Thanks. Will do

Comment: Cut the guy some slack. every invocation of `new` in this context would allocate some memory. There is no "re-use" of the first `new` for the subsequent `new` - compilers don't usually do that. How much memory is allocated per `new`: 1 byte or more (compiler extras, alignment, etc in addition to what you need for your byte variable). Will the allocation be cleaned up as you keep allocating: Probably not in the case you describe. But everyone is free to write their own compiler and CLR which can do things differently than the standard one provided by Microsoft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, the runtime is *not required* to allocate any memory on the heap, if it sees that the memory is not really used. It's just required to act *as if* it did allocate the memory. An approach that can be used to figure out if this optimization can be applied is called [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis).

In practice, any .Net runtime I'm aware of will allocate memory on the heap 100 times for your code. They're not smart enough to realize it's not necessary.

Also note that using `new` on a `struct` (or an `enum`) will not allocate any memory on the heap. But that's not really relevant here, since you have a `class`, not a `struct`.

Comment: Thank you for an informed answer. Using a long as "stuff" and 10 billion iterations, struct runs 5.6 times faster and garbage collection is decreased by a factor of 143 on my setup